# How to set secure websocket connection using websocket-server and node.js

Tags: node.js, websocket, wss

I can't set secure websocket connection using websocket-server and node.js

**server side**

```
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(PRIVATE_KEY),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(CERTIFICATE)
};

// create web server
var server = ws.createServer(options);
server.listen(8000);
...
```

**client side**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var wsUri = "wss://url:8000";


    function init() {            
        websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
    }

    ...

    window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
</script>
```

But it works for ws

```
var wsUri = "ws://url:8000";
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which browser are you using? Different browsers support different versions of the WebSocket spec, only Chrome 14 and Firefox 7 support the latest draft 8 of the WS spec. Also how are you handling the 'handshake' to establish a connection with the WebSocket?

Comment: I'm using google chrome (v. 15)
For handshake I use self signed certificate. 

I tried plain https server built-in nodejs, it works fine with this certificate, I mean https://url:port. But there is something wrong with websockets implementation in websocket-server package.

Comment: I meant what node.js package are you using to handle WebSockets? Or are you rolling your own solution? Have you tried Worlize/WebSocket-Node https://github.com/Worlize/WebSocket-Node ? EDIT: Just noticed you mentioned something called 'websocket-server', is this a package for node.js? Can you provide a link to it?

Comment: here is the link https://github.com/miksago/node-websocket-server
Yep, it's nodejs package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the readme for [websocket-server](https://github.com/miksago/node-websocket-server):

> This is a server for the WebSocket Protocol. It currently to works
>   with both draft75 and draft76 of the protocol specification.

Chrome v15 no longer uses draft75/draft76. It uses the latest version 8 of the WebSocket spec and isn't compatible with older drafts (both the handshake mechanism and the way data is sent have changed). This could be your problem.

Try using a node.js package that supports the newer WebSocket spec, I'd recommend [Worlize/WebSocket-Node](https://github.com/Worlize/WebSocket-Node) or you could give [socket.io](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io) a try.